# One content type with several fields or several content types?

Tags: nodes

currently I'm working on a master data management system in Drupal.
We've got products for different sales channels (like ebay, magento, amazon etc.)
On field where I'm struggling is: Category
(CatEbay, CatMagento, CatAmazon, etc.)
for one and the same product.

Two options:
Add more fields to a sales channel (content type) or add different sales channels.
If I've got different sales channels, I need to implement a relation as well as the translation might be tricky.

If I simply add several category fields, it doesn't look very nice, but makes everything quite easy.

There is something like:
https://drupal.org/project/bundle_inherit
but does it work with translation or export node + it's alpha2 and we are in a production environment ... maybe it just adds complexity without a lot of benefit.

Would there be a disadvantage to point out by going the 'adding fields' way?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

According to me,

1. You should only build one content type : "Product". Create the required fields according to your need.
2. Then, Create taxonomy terms like "Clothing, Electronics, etc." and then use [entity_reference](https://drupal.org/project/references) module to refer the node(i.e Product in this case).
3. That's it, Done.
4. Just create some products and go to taxonomy and add products.
5. For displaying products on page, You should plan to theme taxonomy pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding fields is the right way to go. I suggest you to create a taxonomy vocabulary for the categories and add a term reference field to your content type.

Comment: It seems to be the easiest way to go, that's true. 
For the categories I'd have several categories that reflect the foreign systems (Magento taxonomy, ebay taxonomy, ..)?